# Takes a long time to upload to Cloud on Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm trying to upload 3 files (about 150MB each) and so far it has taken about 12 hours over a 2 day period and it is still in progress and slows down my internet connection considerably, I'm using about 1400Kib upload speed, on a wired connection, and have used so far 118 MB out of 5GB, my OS is Ubuntu 11.10. Why is it so slow?

Answer (score 1):

im not entirely sure myself, as i had the same problem.

oddly enough i found that uploading one file at a time works at a decent rate, but i could never get a second to upload unless i closed and restarted the program.

also, if you upload from your android via 4g connection it shows as uploading much faster (why they included a progress bar on the phone app and not on the desktop app is beyond me)